# Using SQL views in asp.net dynamic data site

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, dynamic-data

I've spent a fair while googling and haven't been able to get a definitive answer to this.

I'm reasonable new to asp.net but have created a dynamic data site which is all working when I use database tables in my dbml, however if I try and link to a view in the database it is automatically displayed by the scaffolding but no hyperlink to the table it links to.

Is this possible?

An example of what I'm working with:

This works:

```
TableA: id
TableB: id, TableA_id
```

When i view Table A, i get a field with "View TableBs", When i look at TableB i see a link to "TableA"

However when I have this:

```
ViewA: id
TableB: id, ViewA_id
```

Looking at ViewA in the browser there's nothing for TableB, Looking at TableB i can see ViewA_id but it's just text and not a link.

I've tried creating a partial class and using the UiHint(ForiegnKey) but this gave an error (assuming because it's not a real FK field in the DB).

Thanks in advance!

**Edited to add**:

I get this when i used the UIHint for foreign key:

```
'xxxx_id' is not a foreign key column and cannot be used here.
Line 37: 
Line 38:     protected string GetDisplayString() {
Line 39:         return         FormatFieldValue(ForeignKeyColumn.ParentTable.GetDisplayString(FieldValue));
Line 40:     }
```

I get the feeling I'm on the right track, but missing something. Is there a way to "force" it to work out it's a link to another table?

Comment: Are you just trying to display the data from the view?  You won't be able to do the CRUD operations on a view, which may be why Dynamic Data doesn't like it.

Comment: I'm not trying to do CRUD on the view (or any tables actually) it's just displaying the data. I'd like to display links to/from views that are joined up using the dbml tool in the way you can for tables.